# Attaching "Application Load Balancer" to "Auto Scaling Group" in Terraform gives error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-elb, aws-auto-scaling

When one creates an ASG (Auto Scaling Group) in AWS Console there is option which can be checked "receive traffic from one or more load balancers"?

I was trying to do same using the "aws_autoscaling_attachment" resource, however I'm getting error below. I can see that the "MyALBWP" is present in the console.

> ERROR: Failure attaching AutoScaling Group MyWPReaderNodesASGroup with Elastic Load Balancer: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:262702952852:loadbalancer/app/MyALBWP/ef1dd71d87b8742b:
> ValidationError: Provided Load Balancers may not be valid. Please ensure they exist and try again.

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "MyWPLC" {
  name          = "MyWPLCReaderNodes"
  #count                = 2     Was giving error as min, max size is mentioned in ASG
  #name_prefix          = "LC-"  Error: "name_prefix": conflicts with name
  image_id      =  aws_ami_from_instance.MyWPReaderNodes.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.MyWebInstanceProfile2.name # Attach S3 role to EC2 Instance
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.WebDMZ.id]  # Attach WebDMZ SG
  user_data          = file("./AutoScaleLaunch.sh")
  lifecycle {
    #prevent_destroy       = "${var.prevent_destroy}"
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
  #   tags = {     NOT VALID GIVES ERROR
  #   Name = "MyWPLC"
  # }

}

# # Create AutoScaling Group for Reader Nodes
# Name: MyWPReaderNodesASGroup
# Launch Configuration : MyWPLC
# Group Size : 2
# Network : Select your VPC
# Subnets : Select your public Subnets
# Receive traffic from Load Balancer   <<< Tried in "aws_autoscaling_attachment" gives 
# Target Group : MyWPInstances
# Health Check : ELB or EC2, Select ELB
# Health check grace period : 60 seconds
# tags name MyWPReaderNodesGroup

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "MyWPReaderNodesASGroup" {
  name                      = "MyWPReaderNodesASGroup"
  # We want this to explicitly depend on the launch config above
  depends_on = [aws_launch_configuration.MyWPLC]
  max_size                  = 2
  min_size                  = 2
  health_check_grace_period = 60
  health_check_type         = "ELB"
  desired_capacity          = 2
  force_delete              = true
  launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.MyWPLC.id
  vpc_zone_identifier       = [aws_subnet.PublicSubNet1.id, aws_subnet.PublicSubNet2.id]
  target_group_arns = [aws_lb_target_group.MyWPInstancesTG.arn] #  A list of aws_alb_target_group ARNs, for use with Application or Network Load Balancing.
  #target_group_arns = [aws_lb.MyALBWP.id] #  A list of aws_alb_target_group ARNs, for use with Application or Network Load Balancing.
  #error: ValidationError: Provided Target Groups may not be valid. Please ensure they exist and try again.
  # tags = {        NOT REQUIRED GIVES ERROR  : Error : Inappropriate value for attribute "tags": set of map of string required.
  #   Name = "MyWPReaderNodesGroup"
  # }
}

# Create a new load balancer attachment
# ERROR: Failure attaching AutoScaling Group MyWPReaderNodesASGroup with Elastic Load Balancer: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:262702952852:loadbalancer/app/MyALBWP/ef1dd71d87b8742b: 
# ValidationError: Provided Load Balancers may not be valid. Please ensure they exist and try again.

resource "aws_autoscaling_attachment" "asg_attachment_elb" {
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.MyWPReaderNodesASGroup.id
  elb                    = aws_lb.MyALBWP.id
}
```

Comment: It looks like you already should have the target group of your ALB attached by using the `target_group_arns` parameter (the uncommented out one is correctly pointing to a target group while the commented out one is pointing to an ALB/NLB which is why you get that error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NOTE on AutoScaling Groups and ASG Attachments: Terraform currently provides both a standalone ASG Attachment resource (describing an ASG attached to an ELB), and an [AutoScaling Group resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html) with `load_balancers` defined in-line. At this time you cannot use an ASG with in-line load balancers in conjunction with an ASG Attachment resource. Doing so will cause a conflict and will overwrite attachments.

From [Resource: aws_autoscaling_attachment docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_attachment.html#alb_target_group_arn).

You have two options:

1. Delete the **aws_autoscaling_attachment** resource
2. Remove the **target_group_arns** argument from the **aws_autoscaling_group** resource, remove use the **elb** argument from the **aws_autoscaling_attachment** resource, and add **alb_target_group_arn** to the **aws_autoscaling_attachment** resource

Option 1 looks like this:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "MyWPReaderNodesASGroup" {
  name                      = "MyWPReaderNodesASGroup"
  # We want this to explicitly depend on the launch config above
  depends_on = [aws_launch_configuration.MyWPLC]
  max_size                  = 2
  min_size                  = 2
  health_check_grace_period = 60
  health_check_type         = "ELB"
  desired_capacity          = 2
  force_delete              = true
  launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.MyWPLC.id
  vpc_zone_identifier       = [aws_subnet.PublicSubNet1.id, aws_subnet.PublicSubNet2.id]
  target_group_arns = [aws_lb_target_group.MyWPInstancesTG.arn] #  A list of aws_alb_target_group ARNs, for use with Application or Network Load Balancing.
}
```

Option 2 looks like this:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "MyWPReaderNodesASGroup" {
  name                      = "MyWPReaderNodesASGroup"
  # We want this to explicitly depend on the launch config above
  depends_on = [aws_launch_configuration.MyWPLC]
  max_size                  = 2
  min_size                  = 2
  health_check_grace_period = 60
  health_check_type         = "ELB"
  desired_capacity          = 2
  force_delete              = true
  launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.MyWPLC.id
  vpc_zone_identifier       = [aws_subnet.PublicSubNet1.id, aws_subnet.PublicSubNet2.id]
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_attachment" "asg_attachment_elb" {
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.MyWPReaderNodesASGroup.id
  alb_target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.MyWPInstancesTG.arn
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `aws_autoscaling_attachment` resource should use the `alb_target_group_arn` parameter. You can use the `aws_lb_target_group.MyWPInstancesTG.arn` parameter you used for creating your autoscaling group.

The `elb` parameter is for classic load balancers, not application load balancers.

More information is available [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_attachment.html#alb_target_group_arn).